# Could I write this implementation of Iterator.next() without a local variable (double linked list)

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment where I am supposed to make a given doubly-linked list class Iterable. I am not allowed to change or add any extra methods. This code works just fine, I was just curious if I could write it without using a local variable. `n` is the current node that the iterator is on. `n.succ` is the next node in the list (which is null if there is not a next value). `n.pred` is the previous node in the list (which is null if there is not a previous value). `n.val` is the value stored in the node. Here is what I currently have (which works fine).

```
/** Return the next element to enumerate. */
public @Override E next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node n1 = n;
    n = n.succ;
    return n1.val;
}
```

I can't say

```
n = n.succ;
return n.pred.val;
```

because if `n.succ` is null, then `n.pred` will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: `return n == null ? tail.val : n.pred.val;` You could also use a **cyclical double linked list**. Then it would just be your `n.pred.val`.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid the variable by some convoluted code, but why would you?

Comment: @JoopEggen That works! I cannot use a cyclical double linked list because its an assignment for a class where I have to use THEIR homemade doubly linked list class. If you want, post your comment as an answer and I will upvote and checkmark it for the reputation.

Comment: Go ahead. Having a variable is not bad either. Like in implementing `i++`. Also you can do `return (n == null ? tail : n.pred).val;`